# Using a query which returns multiple in another query

Tags: sql, postgresql, grafana

I would like to perform multiple queries on one table in my database. A summary of the table is as follows:

```
+-------+-----+
| user  | val |   
+-------+-----+
| user1 |  1  |   
| user2 |  2  |    
| null  |  5  |  
| null  |  5  |   
| user3 |  5  |
| user1 |  1  |  
+-------+-----+
```

The queries individually are simple however, I'm struggling to put them together. The queries are as follows:

1. I would first like to query the user column for any distinct non null user values which will return multiple.
2. With the results of the query above I would like to count the total number for each user that has a particular val.

So far I have this:

```
SELECT 
( SELECT user from db where user='{someuser}'),
( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM db WHERE user='{someuser}' AND val= '1'), 
( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM db WHERE user='{someuser}' AND val= '2');
```

Essentially What I need to is replace {someuser} with each of the users present in the user column.

I'm expecting my output to look like this

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| user  | val=1 | val=2 | total |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| user1 |     1 |     1 |     2 |
| user2 |     1 |     0 |     1 |
| user3 |     0 |     0 |     0 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm . . . I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
select user, sum(case when val = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as val_1,
       sum(case when val = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as val_2,
       count(*) as total
from t
group by user
order by user;
```

Comment: When there is user2 the '1' will occur on Val_2 instead of val_1 little different from the expected o/p, may be thats just the typo by @faj123